# SQL Server Simple Group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple problem , Although i believe its simple , am not able to figure out the same.

Consider i have the below table with exactly same data as given below :

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #temp
>     (
>     link varchar(255),
>     number INT,
>     fname varchar(255)            
>     )
>
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abc',1,'f1')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abc',2,'f2')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abc',3,'f3')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abc',4,'f6')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abc',10,'f100')
>
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abe',-1,'f0')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abe',1,'f1')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abe',2,'f2')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abe',3,'f3')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abe',4,'f6')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('abe',20,'f200')
>
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('cbe',-1,'f0')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('cbe',1,'f1')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('cbe',2,'f2')
>     insert into #temp VALUES ('cbe',3,'f3')
> ```

Now for a given link , i need to get the max 'number' and the corresponding 'fname' which has the max 'number' for the given 'link'.

1)Ex : if link is 'abc' , output should be
**abc, 10, f100**

2)Ex : if link if 'abe' , Output should be
**abe, 20, f200**

3)Now link can be also given as a pattern , like (link  like 'ab%') , so output should be

**abc, 10, f100**

**abe, 20, f200**

4)if (link like 'cb%') , so output should be
**cbe, 3, f3**

Any help in writing this group by query. I have a solution using CAST and string concat like below , but that seems to be in-efficient.

```
select link,number,fname from #temp 
where link like 'ab%' and link+'_'+CAST(number AS varchar(255)) 
in (select link+'_'+CAST(MAX(number) AS varchar(255)) from #temp 
group by link)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using a self join:

```
SELECT x.link,
       x.number,
       x.fname
  FROM #temp x
  JOIN (SELECT t.link,
               MAX(t.number) AS max_number
          FROM #temp t
      GROUP BY t.link) y ON y.link = x.link
                        AND y.max_number = x.number
```

### Using a CTE and ROW_NUMBER (SQL Server 2005+):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT x.link,
          x.number,
          x.fname,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.link
                                ORDER BY x.number DESC) rank
     FROM #temp x)
SELECT c.link, 
       c.number,
       c.fname
  FROM cte c
 WHERE c.rank = 1
```

Comment: Moring. And how are you on this saturday morning? X-)

Comment: @astander: Barely conscious.  How's the weekend treating you so far?

Comment: Bit of a hangover, but that is expected after an awesome party... Its getting that time of the year where everybody starts to wind down. You must almost be off to bed???

Comment: @astander: I might linger a little longer, with your permission

Comment: hehe, but then you take all the votes X-) Might as weel get me another beer... Start the day off well. Later